# Sharepoint 2013 workflow copy element from one list to another

Tags: workflow

How to copy by workflow creating element in one list to another list.

I can run a workflow, but manualy. I push a tick  on "Start workflow automatically when an item is created", but it don't work.

Comment: Are you using designer workflows or visual studio workflow?

Comment: Designer workflow

Comment: did you publish the workflow?

Comment: Are you trying on the Flow App environment? i've created same flows and works perfectly with the "Start workflow automatically when an item is created" option. [![image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytWSq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytWSq.png)
[![flowAPP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9JeX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9JeX.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing what I think you are doing, you checked "start workflow when item is created" through the website ribbon option, but didn't check this option in Sharepoint designer.  If it is left unchecked, everytime you republish your workflow through designer, it resets the start options of the workflow to the default option, which is to only start manually.

Then, in Sharepoint designer, there is an action to create an element in any list, and set it's values with the values of the current element, effectively copying it.

Comment: I do it on the Designer I checked there in designer not in the browser.

Comment: Try doing it on both.  When does the option reset back to manual only?

Comment: When I try to go to setting to manual on workflow in browser it told me  that I only can do this in Designer.

Comment: Really?  Hmm, haven't heard of that.  What version of sharepoint are you using?  Is the notification from sharepoint itself, or is it an environment permission issue, where it is set up to be that way?

Comment: When I go to the list, end there I will take click a worcflow name it told me that a workflow only created in Sharepoint Designer I can edit

Comment: So, when exactly does the workflow go back to the original settings?  Does it reset when you publish the workflow?  Or is it showing you that the "Start when item is created" option is checked in designer, and it is just not executing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Farm admin account do not start workflow automatically. If you are using farm admin account to add item to list, just change your account to a normal account and then try too add item again.